Square face texture using texture nodes or so (first filling from the edge or outside)
I would like to create a texture that first comes from the edge, offsets and then fills the area (face, or open [not closed geometry]). I believe we can use proximity vektors but not sure how to connect these together as a mix shader only mixes.
How would I go about this as I have read some material, but it's all more complex than this. 

In principle you can't do it in a shader alone,  because it needs more information than is given to it. Even with using geometry nodes, compositing etc. I think it's hard...

What is your goal? Are you looking to create outlines via a shader?

My goal is to be able to apply it to a shield for example, and then suddenly the shield has a boarder on the faces I applied it to.

I think I misunderstood your sketch: I though you want the coloring based on the distance from the silhouette, which depends on the camera angle. But instead you just want to mark some edges, and get distance from that? Perhaps you could operate on the UV space, therefore flattening the problem into 2D, which is the same as this: Procedural Border Detection on a Flat Object
